# Internal server error: Cannot read property 'useQwikCityEnv' of null

Tags: qwik

I'd followed the integration instructions to connect my builder.io account to my qwik application running on `localhost:5143` and setup a test page to start playing with visual editor but I got this error on localhost:

```
10:47:31 PM [vite] Internal server error: Cannot read property 'useQwikCityEnv' of null
  File: /Users/mra/development/personal/qwik/node_modules/@builder.io/qwik-city/index.qwik.mjs:265:14
  263|  };
  264|  const QwikCityProvider = /* @__PURE__ */ componentQrl(inlinedQrl(() => {
  265|    const env = useQwikCityEnv();
     |                ^
  266|    if (!env?.params)
  267|      throw new Error(`Missing Qwik City Env Data`);
```

and I didn't find any resources online why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

After several tries I'd found the issue and the solution:

instead of running the local app with `dev` command which is a browser only render, you should run `start` command to enable local ssr as well;

```
npm run start
```